# Weak convergence of stochastic integral and its quadratic variation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

Consider a sequence of stochastic processes $Z^{(n)}$ and a stochastic process $Z$ on $[0,1]$ such that
$$
\int_0^\cdot Z^{(n)}_t dW_t \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} \int_0^\cdot Z_t dW_t
$$
converge in distribution as processes. Is it true that than also the quadratic variation processes converge in distribution, i.e.
$$
\int_0^\cdot \left(Z^{(n)}_t\right)^2 dt\overset{d}{\longrightarrow} \int_0^\cdot Z^2_t dt 
$$
as processes?

---

A similar question asking for weak convergence of the quadratic variations at time 1 under the assumption that the stochastic integrals converge weakly at time 1 can be found under [Weak convergence of stochastic integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1497252/weak-convergence-of-stochastic-integral).